# Can i host/deploy React application in iis server?

Tags: reactjs, iis, deployment

I am new to React. I have created a simple React application. I wanted to explore deployment and hosting options for React. I have worked previously in Angular and it can be deployed in IIS. can we do the same for React. Please enlighten me.

Comment: You can.  `reactjs` is just a frontend framework.  Certainly, certain technologies work with it better than others.  But nothing stops you from deploying reactjs on IIS.

Comment: Yes it it is with minimum settings as Virtual Directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could follow below steps to host or publish the application to IIS.

1.Open cmd and locate your react application folder

[image]

2.Build the project to production folder.

```
npm run build
```

[image]

3.Open IIS management console and create a new web sites and use the build path as the physical path. for example: D:\ReactAppTest\my-app\build

Notice: You should pay attention to your port number.

[image]

4.Then you could use that port number to access your react application. For example: http://localhost:9965/

[image]